# How to input JSON data with dynamic data array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

Person 1 inputs data and the data array looks like this :

```
{
  "type": "1",
  "name": "John", 
  "phone":"898171"
}
```

Person 2 has not set the phone and the data array looks like this :

```
{
  "type": "1",
  "name": "Lisa"
}   // only write 2 array...
```

I have source code in my controller like this :

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

if(!$data['phone']->iSEmpty){
   echo "you haven't set the phone number!"
}
```

But this is not working. I get the following error when Person 2 inputs the data -

> "Undefined index: phone"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to check a value of an undefined key.

You could use array_key_exists to check it:

```
if (!array_key_exists('phone', $data)) {
    echo "you haven't set the phone number!";
}
```

Comment: before i read your comment, I try like this array_key_exists($data['phone']); ... haha.. Thank you..  your solution is working!!!

Comment: I'm glad to know I could help you! :)

Comment: If it's working, could you accept as correct answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(!isset($data['phone'])){ echo "you haven't set the phone number!" }
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try" this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: One can try lots of things... I don't have time to try. Did you try before posting this?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Next time i will give a explanation.